# Question about app.exec() and looping in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Isn't `app.exec()` an infinite loop that returns `main()` ?

I want to loop the *server client communication* below but it get executed just ones and then the main function ends with `app.exec()`

I am new both to Qt and C++, how can I manage this looping?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "Waiting for the next request " << endl;
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    //  Prepare our context and socket
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t socket(context, ZMQ_REP);
    socket.bind("tcp://*:2424");
    zmq::message_t request;


    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    VideoStreamer videoStreamer;
    imageProvider *liveOriginalImageProvider(new imageProvider);
    imageProvider *liveMaskedImageProvider(new imageProvider);

    //********SERVER CLIENT COMMUNICATION BEGINS******//

    // Wait for next request from client
    cout << "Waiting for the next request ." << endl;
    socket.recv(&request);
    cout << "Waiting for the next request.. " << endl;
    string replyMessage = string(static_cast<char *>(request.data()), request.size());

    // Print out received message
    cout << "Received from client (Python): " + replyMessage << endl;

    //  See the gradual sending/replying from client
    sleep(1);

    //  Send reply back to client
    string msgToClient("W");
    zmq::message_t reply(msgToClient.size());
    memcpy((void *) reply.data(), (msgToClient.c_str()), msgToClient.size());
    socket.send(reply);

    //*********SERVER CLIENT COMMUNICATION ENDS**********//

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("VideoStreamer",&videoStreamer);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("liveOriginalImageProvider",liveOriginalImageProvider);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("liveMaskedImageProvider",liveMaskedImageProvider);

    engine.addImageProvider("liveOriginal",liveOriginalImageProvider);
    engine.addImageProvider("liveMasked",liveMaskedImageProvider);


    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    engine.load(url);

    QObject::connect(&videoStreamer,&VideoStreamer::originalImage,liveOriginalImageProvider,&imageProvider::updateImage);
    QObject::connect(&videoStreamer,&VideoStreamer::maskedImage,liveMaskedImageProvider,&imageProvider::updateImage);

    return app.exec();
}
```

**---------UPDATE---------**

I created this thread in **thread.h**

```
class MyThread : public QThread{
public slots:
    void run();
};
```

in **thread.cpp** i declared the method:

```
void MyThread :: run() {
    //  Prepare our context and socket
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t socket(context, ZMQ_REP);
    socket.bind("tcp://*:2424");
    zmq::message_t request;

    //********SERVER CLIENT COMMUNICATION BEGINS******//

    // Wait for next request from client
    cout << "Waiting for the next request ." << endl;
    socket.recv(&request);
    cout << "Waiting for the next request.. " << endl;
    string replyMessage = string(static_cast<char *>(request.data()), request.size());

    // Print out received message
    cout << "Received from client (Python): " + replyMessage << endl;

    //  See the gradual sending/replying from client
    sleep(1);

    //  Send reply back to client
    string msgToClient("W");
    zmq::message_t reply(msgToClient.size());
    memcpy((void *) reply.data(), (msgToClient.c_str()), msgToClient.size());
    socket.send(reply);

    exec();
    //*********SERVER CLIENT COMMUNICATION ENDS**********//
}
```

in **main.cpp** I called it:

```
QThread *thread = new QThread();

MyThread *myThread = new MyThread();
myThread->moveToThread(thread);
myThread->connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), myThread, SLOT(run()));

thread->start();
```

I get `Error: Class declaration lacks Q_OBJECT macro.`
Doesn't QThread inherit the QObject? How can I call the loop properly?

Comment: You can either run the zeroMQ stuff on a separate thread (read up on QThread), or you can try connecting the zeroMQ socket to the event loop. The latter would entail creating a new QTcpSocket, adopting the zeroMQ socket with `setSocketDescriptor`, and then adding listeners to `onReadyRead` to actually read (and possibly process) a zeroMQ message. A quick Google found https://github.com/jonnydee/nzmqt , which is a "seamless interface between 0MQ and Qt". I highly suggest you try that one first.

Comment: No, it is not an infinite loop (it would never return if it were), and it does not return `main()` - calling `main` is undefined.

Comment: `app.exec()` isn't an "infinite loop that returns `main()` - it's what starts Qt's event loop inside of `QApplication`.  Your ZMQ objects need to live somewhere in one of the QObjects managed by the application and perform their I/O on the event loop.

Comment: I couldn't understand what is meant by "connecting the zeroMQ socket to the event loop".. Where is this event loop and how am I going to write my zmq codes in it..

Answer (score 0):

One of the main projects I work on right now uses Qt and ZMQ - Your ZMQ sockets need to live inside a `QObject` that runs on the application's event loop, not inside the `main()` function of your application

Here's a **very** abridged view of how one of our ZMQ sockets communicates on the Qt event loop - the app has a `ZMQ_SUB` socket connected to a `ZMQ_PUB` socket on the other end publishing events from a hardware interface

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   QApplication app(argc, argv);
   ...
   ConnectionManager connMgr; // Create connection class - is a QObject subclass
   connMgr.connect(target);

   MainWindow mainWin; // Create GUI classes

   return app.exec();
}
```

```
void ConnectionManager::connect(std::string target)
{
    context = zmq_ctx_new();

    zsocket = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_SUB);
    zmq_connect(zsocket, (connection + ":" + REQUEST_PORT).c_str());
    ...

    QTimer pollTimer;
    pollTimer.callOnTimeout(this, &ConnectionManager::onPollTimer);
    pollTimer.start(100);
}

void ConnectionManager::onPollTimer()
{
    uint16_t length = 0;

    const size_t buffer_length = 1024;
    uint8_t* buffer = new uint8_t[buffer_length];

    do
    {
        int64_t more = 0;
        size_t more_size = sizeof more;
        auto len = zmq_recv(zsocket, buffer + length, buffer_length - length, ZMQ_NOBLOCK);
        if (len == -1)
        {
            return;
        }
        else if (len > 0)
        {
            length += len;
            auto rc = zmq_getsockopt(socket, ZMQ_RCVMORE, &more, &more_size);
        }
    } while (more);

    std::cout << "Received" << length << "bytes";
    HandleMessage(buffer, length); // Process the incoming message
}
```

In essence, `app.exec()` DOES create an infinite loop, but that loop exists within the `QApplication` object, not one that just repeatedly runs the `main()` function where it was called from, and to make use of that loop your application should create additional instances of `QObject` subclasses and use the signal/slot/QEvent/QTimer mechanisms to perform actions in response to user actions/input events/time intervals

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but this is really hard for me to implement. Is it possible to go through this situation using the codes I wrote above?

Comment: In your question you stated "I am new to both Qt and C++" - are you new to programming in general or have you written in other languages and you're just now trying something in C++/Qt for the first time?  I ask because what you're attempting here is not something I would recommend trying to implement as a beginner programmer until you've gotten much more familiar with the language in general, and then familiarized yourself with how the Qt application event loop and signal/slot mechanisms work, as these are fundamental mechanisms for writing Qt applications in general